# Oracle: get name of procedure that made a update to a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a trigger on a table that logs all the modifications.

What I miss is the information which (procedure) made the changes to the record. I tried with `OWA_UTIL.WHO_CALLED_ME`, but this does not work in triggers.

Is there some other way to get the information I need ?

Thanks
Andreas

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to parse a string returned by [`dbms_utility.format_call_stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i997163) function.

Example setup:

1)  tables: `t1` - monitored table, `t1_log` - contains log of changes in `t1`.

```
create table t1(id number)
/

create table t1_log(
    old_id    number,          -- value of t1.id before modification
    new_id    number,          -- value of t1.id after modification
    op_type   varchar2(20),    -- type of modification
    tracelist varchar2(4000)   -- stack trace output
)
/
```

2)  Procs to call

```
create or replace procedure p1(pId number)
is
begin
  insert into t1(id) values(1);
end;
/

create or replace procedure p2(pId number)
is
begin
  update t1 set id = id + 1 where Id = pId;
end;
/

create or replace procedure p3(pId number)
is
begin
  p1(pId);
  p2(pId);

  delete t1 where id = pId + 1;
end;
/
```

3) Trigger on table `t1` for monitoring of changes.

```
create or replace trigger t1_log_writer 
  after insert or update or delete
  on t1 
  for each row
declare
  vOpType varchar2(20);
begin

  if(inserting) then
    vOpType := 'insert';
  elsif(updating) then
    vOpType := 'update';
  elsif(deleting) then
    vOpType := 'delete';
  else
    vOpType := 'undefined';
  end if;

  insert into t1_log(
    old_id, new_id, op_type, tracelist
  ) values(
    :old.id, :new.id, vOpType, dbms_utility.format_call_stack
  );

end;
/
```

4) Test script:

```
insert into t1(id) values(3)
/

begin
  p3(1);
end;
/

select old_id, new_id, op_type, tracelist from t1_log
/
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle example</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6087c/2)

Please note that in example new line character `chr(10)` replaced with `<NEWLINE>` string because this char stripped from HTML output.

Sample stack trace output:

```
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
 object line object
 handle number name
9CA997A8 1 anonymous block
9C876104 15 USER_4_6087C.T1_LOG_WRITER
9FFBEAA8 4 procedure USER_4_6087C.P2
A494E0FC 5 procedure USER_4_6087C.P3
A495FC80 3 anonymous block
```